# Database design for Unitconvertion Table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

i am trying to design a table for storing unit this table is used for unit convertion also the structure of my table is like in the image

[image: table Structure]

is this table structure enough for convertion of units from one type to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *enough*, but, it would prove unnecessarily difficult to query. For example, imagine if someone queries "how many kilograms are in a ton? Or in a milligram?". You'd have to have many rows with "Kilograms" that reference each other, or alternatively run a query a couple of times until you get to the level you need.

Usually, you do that in a connecting table. So, using your naming of columns, it would be something like:

`Units (unit_ID, Name, unit_Type, unit_Group, IsDeleted)`

`IsFactorOf(unit_ID, parent_ID, factor)`

where in "IsFactorOf" the unit_ID is FK to child unit, parent_ID is FK to parent unit (child-parent are with regards to `factor` element - 'child is factor times of parent'), and both keys make a PK.

Now you can define how much kilo's are in whatever unit available of the same type by entering the IsFactorOf for each conversion. Obviously, you'll get a two way conversion...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This assumes that the `UnitSymbol` is unique, which is not the case if you mix metric, imperial etc, for example `tblsp` = table-spoon may be imperial, metric, Canadian, US etc. In that case use `UnitID (integer)` as a primary key.